# Qt regopenkeyex link error

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, windows-8

Здравствуйте. Пишу приложение с использованием qt 5 для работы с реестром в windows 8. При компиляции программы возникают следующие ошибки:

> 1) RegistryClass.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный
>   внешний символ **imp__RegCloseKey@4 в функции "public: bool __thiscall
>   RegistryClass::OpenKey(struct HKEY**
>       *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"
>   (?OpenKey@RegistryClass@@QAE_NPAUHKEY__@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>
> 2) RegistryClass.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ **imp__RegOpenKeyExA@20 в функции "public: bool
>   __thiscall RegistryClass::OpenKey(struct HKEY**
>       *,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"
>   (?OpenKey@RegistryClass@@QAE_NPAUHKEY__@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

Не могу понять из за чего это происходит
Исходный код части программы:

```
#include "RegistryClass.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
...
bool RegistryClass::OpenKey(HKEY key, std::string path)
{
    HKEY tempKey;
    int result = (int) RegOpenKeyExA(key,path.c_str(),NULL,KEY_READ,&tempKey);
    RegCloseKey(tempKey);
    return (result == ERROR_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx) сказано, что эти функции находятся в библиотеке advapi32.lib. В файл проекта нужно добавить:

```
LIBS += -ladvapi32
```